# How to restrict time values in YAML Form timepicker?

Tags: datetime, 8

If I use the time element in [YAML Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/yamlform) then I get the options starting from 00:00 and steps of 30 minutes.

Is there a way to restrict the valid options starting from `10:00` to `18:00` and set the steps to 15 minutes?

Comment: This feature is missing and needs to be added. Please create a feature request in the YAML Form module's [issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/yamlform) and I will fix it. After you create the ticket, please add the link to the ticket on D.O from this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a feature request for a contributed module and needs to be posted to the issue queue on Drupal.org

Comment: I created the needed ticket in the YAML Form's module issue queue (https://www.drupal.org/node/2825277) and this question should be closed.